# Dual of a operator space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional real Banach space and $X^*$ be the dual of $X$. I am going to calculate the dual of operator space, $L(X)$. Is it possible to conclude that the dual of $L(X)$ is $L(X^*)$?

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X @>{T:X\to X}>> L(X)\\
@V{f:X\to \mathbb{R}}VV @VV{??(f':L(X)\to \mathbb{R})}V \\
X^* @>>{T':X^*\to X^*}> L(X^*)
\end{CD}

Since, I am new in this topic I do not know much about the theories. If the statement is false then please help me with a counterexample. Also, please tell me in which case we can conclude such. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It can't be equal to that since that wouldn't give you functionals with values in the scalar field. But I'm assuming you'd like to have a canonical isomorphism of sorts?

Comment: @BrunoB I just have edited the question. It was a little typos there. Now it is ok. Yes I want some sort of canonical isomorphism.

Comment: I think this is a bad space, like in the case of the space of bounded sequences. However at least in the case when $X$ is an Hilbert space, the space of bounded operators is the dual of trace class operators.

Comment: @LL3.14 can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: @Tutun: you need to make your question more specific, in the sense of what kind of isomorphism is acceptable to you. Because you are in finite-dimension, $X$ and $X^*$ have the same dimension, and hence $L(X)$, $L(X^*)$, and $L(X^*)$ have the same dimension; this gives you isomorphisms, but definitely boring and non-canonical ones.

Comment: @MartinArgerami actually I want to calculate a dual norm of a operator norm, I have a operator space and I want to calculate the dual of that space. How to proceed? I am not getting any clue. Any suggestion?

Comment: I Imagine the most canonical way to algebraically identify $L(X)^\ast$ with $L(X^\ast)$ is via $L(X)\simeq X^\ast\otimes X$ and tensor-hom adjunction:
$$L(X)^\ast=\operatorname{Hom}(L(X),\mathbb R)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}(X^\ast\otimes X,\mathbb R)\simeq\operatorname{Hom}(X^\ast,\operatorname{Hom}(X,\mathbb R))= L(X^*).$$

Comment: @P.P.Tuong thank you for your valuable input. Can you please tell me from where I can read more about the theory what you have elaborated here?

Comment: @Tutun I personally learned these things from Bourbaki's [*Algebra*](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540642435), chap. III, § 4, nos. 1 and 2. It might be a little hard to get into but I do not know of any nicer reference.